# Overriding specific lines from a parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I have a class `Writer` which has a method `process()`. A subclass, `TextWriter`, extends `Writer`.

I want to use the method `process()` of the parent class, except for the last line of the method, which I want to customize according to the needs of the subclass.

Is there any way I can call `super()` in such a way that I can inherit only specific parts of the parent class's method?

***I know this is bad design, and in such cases interfaces must be used. But I was working on making some changes on some old code, and I was wondering if it is possible to do this.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the joint code in a protected method and have the process method call it, like:

```
public class Writer {


    protected void process_subProcess(){
        //most of process code
    }

    public void process(){
        process_subProcess();
        //specific last line

    }
}
```

Then TextWriter only overrides the bit it needs to. subProcess isn't a great name, consider a better one depending on what the subProcess actually does

```
public class TextWriter extends Writer{

    @Override
    public void process(){
        process_subProcess();
        //different final line
    }

}
```

The joint code is protected so that child classes can access it but you can't accidentally use the subProcess method from outside the package

Comment: I just wanted to mention that, i know it's not possible but it would be an awesome feature of a language. I know you can break down stuff to smaller method etc and just override that small tiny one line method but  it would affect performance a lot so for that reason it would be nice to have. I come from c# and actually solved this problem using .tt files as follows I have class A that has some lines of code and I generate class B using .tt file that just clones it but modifies that specific line or lines that i want. I works for me. And if I fix something in A it's fixed in B automatically

Comment: @IronHide that feels a bit scary. A class is supposed to be allowed to change its implementation how ever it sees fit. If a consuming class has hooked onto a specific line doing a very specific thing on the consumed class then the consumed class can never change anything. The concept of a class having a public api on its external surface and a private interior goes out the window; it's all public api

Comment: well I am not saying it's correct in terms of whole OOP, SOLID etc but, if your top priority is performance and we know that the more function calls the more performance is affected then this is how i solved it but yeah it not something scalable or easy to maintain and understand but it does it's job and it works. On the other hand sometimes you override a method just because one line is different, or condition is different but rest is the same it would be nice if language supported.overriding at statement level somehow.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible in Java.

If you have control over the parent class, you can refactor it to ensure the relevant parts can be overriden. If not, you don't really have another option.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can extract the part that differes between both classes to another methode which you implement differently in each class.

Answer (score 1):

No, You cann't override a certain piece of code. overriding is related to the method not to some line of code

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't do that.**
Best way is [override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) that method in your child class and do your specific work.